# RasPi 3 B fails to reboot - card seems good

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card, boot-issues

My Pi was working fine, but I rebooted it, properly from the menu, and it never came back up.  Did all of the standard troubleshooting.  Moved the card to another Pi (3 B, also), then that Pi didn't boot.  Took the card from the second unit, put it in the first unit, and it booted.  So, it's a problem with the card.  However, putting the card in a reader, the card appears to be fine.  No files changed recently.  But the card isn't a bootable card.

Card-1 won't boot Unit-1 or Unit-2. 
Card-2 boots both Units. 
Card-1 appears to read fine in a reader.

Any leads?  Tips to revive it?  A utility for this type of card?

Thanks

Comment: How can you come to the consclusion that the card seems to be good when it fails?

Comment: I say that it "appears to be fine", only because it's readable, but there also appears to be something wrong with it, because I'm suddenly unable to boot from it.

Comment: Do you get some information from [green LED blinking in a specific pattern](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern)? Can you read all files from the mounted boot partition on a pc e.g. with `sudo find /mnt/sdd1/ -type f -exec cat {} >/dev/null \;`?

Comment: please provide more data about your problem.